# How to strip the CSS code in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, escaping

I have the rails application which accepts the XML output from another application. For some condition the XML tage content come up with CSS code

For example :

```
<\/sample/> .headermenu{float:left;no-repeat right;font-size:0.75em; padding-bottom:3px}, #div{float:left} This is the test value from another site <\/sample/>
```

In my ruby application i have parse the XML content and display the content.

It start displaying CSS content like the above.  I want to display strip the CSS code if exist in the content.

Is their any way . we can do this please help...

Comment: I'd say the other application is wrong, or you're actually parsing XHTML. If you have some control over the other app, tell them they're wrong.

Comment: Hmm. This is an example of the xml you are receiving? If so, it will be very difficult to parse out the css code since it is mixed in with the normal text in a text node. If this isn't an exact clip of the xml you received, please post one, since I don't think you will get a helpful answer from this clipping. :(

Answer (score 0):

`raw` method might help you.It outputs data without escaping a string. 
Check here http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/RawOutputHelper/raw  for more details.

Answer (score -1):

I dont know if this is what you are looking for but you can try [css parser](http://rubygems.org/gems/css_parser) by the way whenever you need a rails or ruby gem just search for it at [rubygems](http://rubygems.org)